# Dell Inspiron 3650 Desktop Windows 10 Windows Defender constantly rebooting

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, windows-error-reporting

Malwarebytes Antivirus was added to the computer and it detected a problem. I rebooted using the Windows button rather than thru Malwarebytes. Windows rebooted to Windows Defender which runs, gives an error `Stopcode 0xc000021a` and then reboots and repeats the cycle over and over.

I used Dell Windows 10 disk and I tried to restore the system to earlier states and received error code:

> 0x80070005  Advanced-System Restore did not complete
>   successfully-files not changed. Could not access a file-antivirus
>   program running-disable antivirus-retry.

Safe boot mode is unavailable. My command line skills are limited.

If possible, I would not want to reinstall Windows 10 because I have numerous downloaded programs and am not sure of the passwords.

Comment: What do you mean "Safe boot mode is unavailable"? What happens when booting to Safe Mode?

Comment: I used the Windows 10 disk to get to the Command Prompt and then entered C:,

Comment: Are you answering my question? What were you planning it should happen when you enter C:?

Comment: At the C: prompt I enabled the F8 safe Boot mode which worked. The options to start in Safe Mode w/wo Internet, Stop Antivirus Program... did not work and I continued to get a blue screen with error message 0xc000021a. I tried using a different Windows 10 Disk and was able to Restore Windows to an earlier state when it was working but I still wound up with the blue screen and error message.

Answer (score 0):

This stopcode usually means that there is a problem with some of the main Windows system files being damaged, sometimes caused by viruses.

What I'd suggest is two steps:

1. Run an antivirus on the PC (it does give you some time to work before it crashes?). Then also run a boot-time scan with an antivirus that has this capability.
2. Since Windows is already damaged a good thing to do is perform a repair via an in-place upgrade. (which basically reinstalls Windows but keeps the programs and files, just like when upgrading an older windows to windows 10.) A good guide for that can be found here: [How to Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) (the **Step 6** method is probably easiest.)

Comment: I reviewed the video and saw that I could only do an In-place Upgrade in Windows which I was not able to access. The good news is that I was able to use another  computer and use  Ashampoo Backup Pro to restore the hard drive. It's working now. Thanks for your help.